# Remove row if cell do not contain specified text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data sheet "Data".

I would like to remove all rows where cells in a range "A2:A(last with value)" does not contain "r=".

```vb
Dep = Sheets("Data").Range("A2").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

For I = Dep To 2 Step -1
    Cells(I, 15).Select
    If Not (Selection.Value = "r=") Then
        Rows(I).Delete
    End If
Next I
```

[image: A1:A12]

Comment: In the loop, you could use only this one-liner: `If Not Cells(i, 15).Value Like "*r=*" Then Rows(i).Delete`. There is no need to select anything.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `If Not (Selection.Value = "r=") Then` (which is looking for an exact match for "r=") with `If InStr(1, Selection.Value, "r=", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then` (which is looking for whether the cell value contains "r=").

This assumes your Sheet "Data" is active at the time the code runs.

Comment: `Dep = Sheets("Data").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

For I = Dep To 2 Step -1
    Cells(I, 15).Select
    If InStr(1, Selection.Value, "r=", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        Rows(I).Delete
    End If
Next I`

This code remover all rows but A1 :/

Comment: Your code is checking the 15th column in the Sheet (ie column O) for "r=" ... are you wanting to check column O? If you want to check, for example, column A then change the 15 to 1

Comment: It's true, i didn't pay enough attention on it. 

I really Appreciate your help

Comment: No problem, happy to help. If you are happy with the answer, can I ask you to accept it (click on the grey check mark).